# Comparing a handled RuntimeError in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

When I handle a Ruby exception and compare it to an exception object that I construct, it evaluates to false. Why is this so?

To give a specific example, why does this print `false`?

```
begin
  raise "An error happened"
rescue => e
end

err = RuntimeError.new("An error happened")
puts e == err
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
begin
  raise "An error happened"
rescue => e
end

err = RuntimeError.new("An error happened")
[e.backtrace,err.backtrace] # => [["-:2:in `<main>'"], nil]
[e.class,err.class]  # => [RuntimeError, RuntimeError]
[e.message,err.message] # => ["An error happened", "An error happened"]
puts e == err
# >> false
```

Documentation of [`#==`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Exception.html#method-i-3D-3D) is saying :

> Equality—If obj is not an Exception, returns false. Otherwise, returns `true` if exc and obj share same **class, messages, and backtrace**.

Now, in your case `e` and `err` has 2 different **backtrace**, thus it returns `false`.